# Convert javascript of checkbox to select type

Tags: javascript, html, web, backend, web-frontend

Earlier the code for the checkbox was

```
<li class="list-group-item">
       <div class="form-check">
        <label class="form-check-label">
          <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input common_check" value="<?= $row['Year']; ?>" id="Year"><?= $row['Year'];  ?>
        </label>
       </div>
  </li>
```

and js for this to get the filtered text was

```
function get_filter(text_id)
{
  var filterData = [];
  $('#'+text_id+':checked').each(function(){
     filterData.push($(this).val());
   });
  return filterData;
}
```

Now if I want to turn this to select option menu bar

```
<option class="common_check" value="<?= $row['Year']; ?>" id="Year"><?= $row['Year'];  ?>
```

So what should be the javascript for this??

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple of things you need to change:

1. It looks like you are allowing the user to select multiple `option`. For that, make sure `multiple` attribute is assigned to your `select` element.
2. Add an `onchange` handler to your `select`
3. Filter all selected indexes

```html
<select id="mySelect" onchange="handler()" multiple>
   <option id="some-id" value="some-value"></option>
</select>
```

```js
var filtered;
function handler() {
    const selector = document.getElementById('mySelect');
    const selected = Array.prototype.filter.call(selector.options, o => o.selected);
    filtered = selected.map(s => s.value);
}
```

Every time you change an option (deselecting it, or adding one) the handler will reassign the array. This will save you the effort of keeping the array unique by not having to check the array every time to see if the value already exists or not.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working snippet, operating on a `<div>` replacing certain keywords inside it:

```js
const txt=document.getElementById("txt");
document.getElementById("mySelect").onchange=ev=>
 txt.innerHTML=[...ev.target.children]
  .filter(o=>o.selected)
  .reduce((t,c)=>t.replaceAll(c.value,"<b>"+c.value+"</b>"),
          txt.textContent)
```

```html
<select id="mySelect" multiple size="7">
   <option>one</option>
   <option>two</option>
   <option>three</option>
   <option>four</option>
   <option>five</option>
   <option>six</option>
   <option>seven</option>
</select>

<div id="txt">This is one place where you will find 
two or three words on four or even
five lines with more then six blanks
between them. But where is the seven? Here is 
another one anyway ...</div>
```